# Two different validation for field yii2

Tags: php, regex, validation, yii2

I have a login form in my application
Here is my LoginForm model.

```
public $login_un;
public $login_pw;
public $remember_me;

public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['login_un', 'login_pw'], 'required'],
        [['login_un'] , 'string', 'min'=> 4, 'max'=>32],
        [['login_pw'] , 'string', 'min'=> 6, 'max'=>32],
        [['login_un'], 'match', 'pattern' => '/^[A-Za-z0-9]{4,32}$/'],
        [['login_pw'], 'match', 'pattern' => '/^[A-Za-z0-9_@%&*]{6,32}$/'],
    ];
}
```

I want to declare login_un as email and username. I have written it's regular expression for username now I want to use regular expression to accept a correct mail too, but as regular expression are not fully tested I won't risk on it.
How can I define a field as email but allow it to match with another pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a fully tested regular expression for email from yii2 documentation

here is my soultion

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['login_un', 'login_pw'], 'required'],
            [['login_un'] , 'string', 'min'=> 4, 'max'=>32],
            [['login_pw'] , 'string', 'min'=> 6, 'max'=>32],
            [['login_un'], 'match', 'pattern' => '/^[A-Za-z0-9]{4,32}$|^[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&\'*+\\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&\'*+\\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?$/'],
            [['login_pw'], 'match', 'pattern' => '/^[A-Za-z0-9_@%&*]{6,32}$/'],
        ];
    }
```

I have to thank yii2 team specially samdark

here is the [resource](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-emailvalidator.html)

Answer (score 1):

The validator is in string form named `'email'` in YII2. You just add is as you added *`'string'`* (for string length checks) and *`'match`* (for *regex*).

Note that if you specify the rule for a single field, you do not need to put it inside an array.

Please see your example modified with the email validation rule, you find this explained in [*Validating Input: Declaring Rules*](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#declaring-rules):

```
public $login_un;
public $login_pw;
public $remember_me;

public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['login_un', 'login_pw'], 'required'],
        [['login_un'], 'string', 'min'=> 4, 'max'=>32],
        [['login_un'], 'match', 'pattern' => '/^[A-Za-z0-9]{4,32}$/'],
        ['login_un', 'email'], # <-- Email validation
        [['login_pw'], 'string', 'min'=> 6, 'max'=>32],
        [['login_pw'], 'match', 'pattern' => '/^[A-Za-z0-9_@%&*]{6,32}$/'],
    ];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. but if we add email type and regular expression it won't validate the none email input @hakre

Comment: which none email input? - and please update your question if that was your actual case you wanted to ask about.

Comment: as I mentioned in my login form I have three fields. I want login_un validate as email `or` username. if input is email it accept but if is not check the username regex.

Comment: IIRC for This or That type of validators you need to create an own one: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#creating-validators - In your case you would create a **UsernameOrEmailValidator**.

Comment: Thank you for your response buddy :)

Answer (score 1):

This could be so much easier. Just leave your regex for the username and run the email-validator only if there is an `@` in the username and vice versa. Yii-validators have the `when`-attribute in which you can provide an anonymous function. If that function returns boolean `true`, the validator gets executed and otherwise not.

Solution for your case:

```
[['login_un'], 'string', 'min'=>4, 'max'=>32],
[['login_un'], 'match', 'pattern'=>'>>>your regular username regex <<<', 'when'=>function($model) {
    return strpos($model->login_un, '@') === false;
}],
[['login_un'], 'email', 'when'=>function($model) {
    return strpos($model->login_un, '@') !== false;
}],
```

All the details to the feature described are explained in the official docs:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-validator.html#$when-detail

Comment: Oh very nice answer. Many Thanks for your response